# Referencing a character's position inside a loop with Python

Tags: python, string, indexing

How can I write a loop in Python that behaves exactly like this JavaScript loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++)
```

That is, I want the variable i to hold the value of the index of the character as I iterate over a string.

Comment: Did you even try to write something yourself?

Answer (score 0):

This will work for what you would like to do

```
for i in range(len(cars)):
    print(i)  # 0, 1, 2, 3, 4...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the range function combined with len:

```
for i in range(len(cars)):
      ... cars[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `enumerate`:

```
for ii, car in enumerate(cars):
    print ii, car
```

assuming cars is a list like:

```
cars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Then, the output is:

```
>>> 0 a
>>> 1 b
>>> 2 c
>>> 3 d
```

Answer (score 0):

Marginally better:

```
for i in xrange(len(cars)):
    print(i)
```

`xrange` is preferable to `range` in most cases. Best to get in the habit of using `xrange`.

Comment: You should add that the behavior of `range` in Python 3 is the same as `xrange` in Python 2, and `xrange` doesn't exist in Python 3

Comment: Yes good observation.